# Is it safe to use helper function in the 500 error page of symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am customizing the 500 error page of my symfony 1.4 application but I am not sure if the i18n helper and other function like `url_for` are safe to use (will not be broken in some situation).

Do you have any experience in using them and what is your advise ?

**EDIT**
Here is my settings:

```
all:
  .settings:
    i18n:                   true
    default_culture:        en
    enabled_modules:        [sfGuardAuth]
    standard_helpers:       [I18N, Partial, Date]
```

Comment: In this page, it seems that all `standard_helpers` from the `settings.yml` file are enabled. I always use `__()` inside this page.

Comment: @j0k I have `i18n` in my `standard_helpers` and just test with `throw new Exception('testing 500 error');` in the action and echoing the availability of various functions in the template: `__()` don't exists, nor `use_helper`, `sfConfig` is set but not `$sf_user`.

Comment: I don't think I've tried to use sfConfig inside. Can we see the `standard_helpers` line from your `settings.yml` (from the env you're currently tested) ?

Comment: @j0k updated my question (I don't use sfConfig, it was just for testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 500 error page indicates that a serious error has happened, and you have no way to know where. It may be in your code, in symfony's code or a config file.

Even though you may be able to use the helpers in some cases, in other cases it would fail utterly and badly (thing WSOD).

Your very best option is to stick to simple php, as if you weren't using a framework.

Answer (score 2):

We are using localization helpers in our 500 pages without any problems. Though you should mind about the fact that the i18n helpers may fail due to non existent translations.

Comment: I doesn't work for me. Please see my updated question and my comment.